# $push with $group in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wrote this query but its not exactly i want how to use push operator for expected result-
Is it not possible to use push with addFields and project pipeline.

```
db.getCollection("event").aggregate([ {$match:{"name":"Add            
to Cart"}}, {$group:{"_id":"browser",count:{$sum:1}}}]);
```

output:

```
{_id:chrome.count:3}
{_id:firefox,count:1}
{_id:edge,count:1}
```

expect output:

```
{
browser:[
{name:"chrome",count:3},
{name:"firefox",count:1}, 
{name:"egde",count:1}
]
}
```

my collection:

```
{
_id:1,
 name:"Add to Cart"
"browser":"chrome"
}
{
_id:2,
name:"Searched",
"browser":"chrome"
}
{
_id:3,
name:"Add To Cart",
"browser":"edge"
}
{
_id:4,
name:"Item View",
"browser":"chrome"
}
{
_id:5,
name:"Add To Cart",
"browser":"Firefox"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use one more [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$browser",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "browser": {
      "$push": {
        "name": "$_id",
        "count": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "_id": 0 }}
])
```